# I need access to use Linked API version 2

Tags: linkedin-api

I tried to migrage current API to v2 as recent announcement by Linkedin "all developers need to migrate their apps to our newest APIs and OAuth 2.0 by March 1, 2019".
I have an app using API v1 with OAuth 2.0 to get personal and company profile, share a post on company page.

I tried test with request to https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me**&projection=(id)
System keep saying "Not enough permissions to access..."
On recent attempt to request help, it redirected to stactoverflow that implied I need to apply for access to LinkedIn's Marketing Developer Program to access this API.
I applied for API access via this page https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program#get-started serveral times.

Until now I haven't received any feedback yet.
That is close to the deadline March 1st to migrate to API version 2.
Please advise what I need to access and develop API v2?

Answer (score 0):

First check what permission you have :
In V2 you have to apply for partner program for using company related API

In V2 for talking basic information you have to use r_liteprofile  + r_emailaddress

r_liteprofile for firstName,lastName,profilePicture,id - https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))

r_emailaddress for getting emailAddress - https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))

Comment: Thank for your answer. Actually I did grant full permission for the App (for development). I submitted partner program twice but still got no response. In case of failure, I guess LinkedIn doesn't tell us right? This is really annoying, looks like LinkedIn want to limit API usage.

Comment: Now mostly you will get reply within 1 to 2 weeks also if they will reject still they will send email to inform you why they have rejected your partner program. Yes for misuse they have restricted API uses

Comment: For more information, my last partner submission is from this 13th January, now is 15th February and no response.